# Openfire Github Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, openfire

I have checked out the latest code from git from following repository
https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire

and setup it in eclipse (Eclipse Platform,Version: 3.8.1,Build id: debbuild ) using following document https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1020

Now when I build the project it works successfully but project shows one error in following file

> "/Openfire/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/container/PluginServlet.java"

error is like

> The type org.apache.tools.ant.Task cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I am working with Master branch.

Answer (score 1):

May be this happens because apache ant jar is not in build path.
Download http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapacheant182jar.htm jar.
Extract zip-> open project openfire->right click->properties->Java Build Path-> Libraries-> Add External Libraries-> browse-> apache-ant-1.8.2.jar -> OK

and Clean-Build your project.